# Fill rows with previous data until new data occurs

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I have two tables that depicts the quantity of goods entering a place and leaving a place in two separate tables. I need a final table that gives me quantity left after corresponding in and out at a date level using SQL.

```
In Table

Date        | Product | Received qty
------------------------------------
10-10-2019  | A       | 30
11-10-2019  | A       | 30
12-10-2019  | A       | 30
13-10-2019  | B       | 40
14-10-2019  | B       | 40
```

```
Out Table

Date        | Product | Out qty
-------------------------------
12-10-2019  | A       | 10
13-10-2019  | A       | 10
14-10-2019  | A       | 10
15-10-2019  | B       | 20
16-10-2019  | B       | 10
```

Expected output

[image: final table]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also What is your expected output.

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far

Answer (score 0):

SELECT i.Data, i.Product, i.Received 'Qty Received',o.Out 'Out qty', (i.Received - o.Out)  'Available in hand'
FROM InTable i LEFT JOIN OutTable o
ON i.Product = o.Product AND i.Date = o.Date

Answer (score 0):

You want a `full join` and a cumulative sum.  I think the logic is:

```
select coalesce(i.date, o.date) as date, 
       coalesce(i.product, o.product) as product,
       coalesce(i.qty, 0) as received,
       coalesce(o.qty, 0) as qty_out,
       (sum(coalesce(i.qty, 0)) over (partition by i.product order by i.date) -
        sum(coalesce(o.qty, 0)) over (partition by o.product order by i.date)
       ) as on_hand

from intable i full join
     outtable o
     on i.date = o.date and i.product = o.product
```